# Translate `cp -r $BASEDIR/*/src/main/resource/* $BASEDIR/target/classes/.` to ant's copy command

Tags: ant

I tried something like this:

```
<copy todir="target/classes">
  <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="*/src/main/resource/**"/>
</copy>
```

but that copies stuff like `target/classes/sub-dir/src/main/resource/file.txt` and I'd like it to be `target/classes/file.txt`. How do I do this? Do I have to use a mapper?

EDIT: I added `<mapper type="regexp" from="^.*/src/main/resource/(.*)$" to="\1"/>` and that seemed to do the trick. (NOTE: I'll clean up the regexp to be tighter later.)

Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: To clarify, do you have a file at `${basedir}/sub-dir/src/main/resource/file.txt` you would like to have copied to `${basedir}/target/classes/file.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested [`<cutdirsmapper>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#cutdirs-mapper) will do the trick...

> [cutdirsmapper] strips a configured number of leading directories from the source file name.

After `<cutdirsmapper>` removes the leading directories, it will preserve whatever remains of the directory structure...

```xml
<copy todir="target/classes">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="*/src/main/resource/**"/>
    <cutdirsmapper dirs="4"/>
</copy>
```

### Before running Ant

```
$ find . -type f
./build.xml
./sub-dir/src/main/resource/another-sub-dir/file2.txt
./sub-dir/src/main/resource/file1.txt
```

### After running Ant

```
$ find . -type f
./build.xml
./sub-dir/src/main/resource/another-sub-dir/file2.txt
./sub-dir/src/main/resource/file1.txt
./target/classes/another-sub-dir/file2.txt
./target/classes/file1.txt
```

Notice how `file2.txt` is still under `another-sub-dir` after the mapping has been applied.

Comment: Thanks, but I do have a dir structure that I need to keep in place. But this is useful if I did not have that requirement.

Comment: @three-cups I've updated my answer to use `<cutdirsmapper>` instead of `flatten`. It sounds like a solution closer to what you're looking for.